# Recipe gets posted but doesn't get saved

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-context

I am creating a recipe app with react and axios. When I try to add new recipe by submitting the form in the form.js, it doesn't get saved and displayed along the other recipes, it only gets printed in the console. I suppose it's something with the axios. any idea?.Apreciate any advices guys[full code](https://github.com/JanLinhart/ackee)

form.js

```
import React from 'react'
import './Form.css'
import {RecipeContext} from './RecipeContext';
import {useContext,useState,useEffect} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

function Form() {
    const [nazev,setNazev]=useState('');
    const[uvodni,setUvodni]=useState('');
    const[ingredience,setIngredience]=useState('');
    const[postup,setPostup]=useState('');
    const[time,setTime]=useState(0);
    const [score,setScore]=useState(0);
    const{recipes,setRecipes}=useContext(RecipeContext)
   
    const onSubmit=e=>{
     
      e.preventDefault()
      const newRecipe={name:nazev,description:postup,ingredients:[ingredience],duration:+time,info:uvodni}
      
      
      
      axios.post("https://cookbook.ack.ee/api/v1/recipes", newRecipe)
      .then(res => setRecipes(res.data))
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
      
      
    
    }
    
    return (
        <>
        <button className="pridat" onClick={onSubmit}>+</button>
        <form className="form" >
          <p className="nazev">Název receptu</p>
          <input type="text" value={nazev}
          onChange={(e) => setNazev(e.target.value)}/>
          <input type="text" className="uvodni" placeholder="Úvodní text"
          value={uvodni}
          onChange={(e) => setUvodni(e.target.value)}/>
          <h2>Ingredience</h2>
          <input placeholder="Vaše ingredience" type="text"
          value={ingredience}
          onChange={(e) => setIngredience(e.target.value)}/>
          <button>+ Přidat</button>
          <input type="text" className="postup" placeholder="Postup"
          value={postup}
          onChange={(e) => setPostup(e.target.value)}/>
         <input type="text" placeholder="Čas" className="cas" value={time}
          onChange={(e) => setTime(e.target.value)}/>
          
        </form>
        </>
    )
          }

export default Form
```

recipelist.js

```
import {RecipeContext} from './RecipeContext';
import {useContext} from 'react';
import Recipe from './Recipe';
import './RecipeList.css'
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'

function RecipeList() {

 const {recipes}=useContext(RecipeContext)
  
  return (
<>
<div className="navbar">
    <h1>Recepty</h1>
    <h3>Počet receptů:{recipes.length}</h3>
  <Link to="/pridat-recept"> <h2 className="plus">+</h2></Link> 
</div>
<div className="recipe-list">
{recipes.map(item=>(
    <Recipe name={item.name} id={item.id} duration={item.duration} score={item.score} key={item.id}/>
))}
</div>
</>

  );
}

export default RecipeList;
```

recipecontext.js

```
import React,{useState,useEffect,createContext,useReducer} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import AppReducer from './AppReducer'


export const RecipeContext=createContext([[],() => {}]);

export default function RecipeProvider(props) {
    const[recipes,setRecipes]=useState([])
    const[state,dispatch]=useReducer(AppReducer,recipes)
    function addRecipe(id){
      dispatch({
        type:'ADD_RECIPE',
        payload:id
      })
    }
  
    useEffect(() => {
  axios.get('https://cookbook.ack.ee/api/v1/recipes?limit=10&offset=0')
  .then(res=>setRecipes(res.data))
  console.log(recipes)
    })   

    
  

    
    return (
       
<RecipeContext.Provider value={{recipes,setRecipes,addRecipe}}>
    {props.children}
</RecipeContext.Provider>
      
    )
}
```

appreducer.js

```
export default (state,action)=>{
    switch(action.type){
  
        case 'ADD_RECIPE':
            return{
                ...state,
                recipes:[action.payload,...state.recipes]
            }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Comment: Add the code related to the RecipeContext. Is your recipe getting saved in the backend?

Comment: I have added it up there

Comment: the context's value seems to be an object with three properties but the initial value passed to `createContext([[],() => {}])` is an array. Also in the reducer, it's best to add the new payload at the end so that the old values don't override it, like `recipes:[...state.recipes, action.payload]`. What's the data type of recipes?

Comment: I now realize that the addrecipe function from recipecontext isnt used in the form...so isnt that why it is not being saved to the backend?

Comment: addRecipe in your case adds a recipe to the recipes array, that might not be the cause if the recipe isn't getting saved in the backend. Also, you have a `setRecipes` function to update the recipes in the FE after the post request. Correct all the things I've mentioned above and also make sure that this isn't an issue with the backend.

Comment: okay so I changed createContext([[],() => {}]) to createContext([() => {}]) and added recipes:[...state.recipes, action.payload]...anything else I might have missed?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226191/discussion-between-ramesh-reddy-and-jendazedniik).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the cookbook API gives you a recipes list whenever you want, you can use it to update the recipes in your app.

```
const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const newRecipe = {
      name: nazev,
      description: postup,
      ingredients: [ingredience],
      duration: +time,
      info: uvodni,
    };

    axios
      .post('https://cookbook.ack.ee/api/v1/recipes', newRecipe)
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data); // confirm if it's the new recipe
        updateRecipes();
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));
  };
```

and in the context, you can add an empty array to `useEffect` to only run that when component mounts and the `updateRecipes` function can be placed here as it's one of things we want to be in the context:

```
const [recipes, setRecipes] = useState([]);
  // the state below is not being used anywhere so I commented it
  // const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(AppReducer, { recipes });
  const updateRecipes = (id) => {
    axios
      .get('https://cookbook.ack.ee/api/v1/recipes?limit=1000&offset=0')
      .then((res) => setRecipes(res.data));
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get('https://cookbook.ack.ee/api/v1/recipes?limit=1000&offset=0')
      .then((res) => setRecipes(res.data));
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to get the recipe context then just append the newRecipe (assuming that your axios post successfully gets added to the Database).

```
      axios.post("https://cookbook.ack.ee/api/v1/recipes", newRecipe)
      .then(res => setRecipes(res.data))
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

to

```
      axios.post("https://cookbook.ack.ee/api/v1/recipes", newRecipe)
      .then(res => setRecipes({
        ...recipes,
        newRecipe
      }))
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
```